# Запрос для вывода определенной новости

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт выводит одну "главную" новость, которая должна держаться 2 дня, после чего должна либо замениться на следующюю новость, либо написать, что мол нет сейчас новостей.

Структу таблицы такая: id, title, text, date. В date лежит время в timestamp формате (время тогда, когда новость была добавлена из админки, хотя мне кажется это не совсем правильно).

Так вот, помогите составить запрос в mysql, который бы выводил нужную мне новость.

**Добавлено.**

```
$q1 = mysql-query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE
                  `date` > date-sub(NOW(), interval 2 day) 
                  ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Этот запрос работает все-таки немного не так, как нужно, если в базе несколько новостей, то более новая запись перебивает старую, даже если не прошло 2 дней.

Можно такое решить средствами mysql? Или, наверно, придется при добавлении новой записи подстраивать дату, чтоб считало правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```sql
select id, title, txt, dt from news 
where dt > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 2 day) 
order by dt desc limit 1;
```

или так, если нужны ВСЕ записи не старше 2х дней (появятся сначала последняя добавленная):

```sql
select id, title, txt, dt from news 
where dt > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 2 day) 
order by dt desc;
```

Написано в пол-четвертого ночи, поэтому на кратость и оптимальное решение не претендую - оптимизируйте! ;) - уже исправил даже...

Comment: можете также воспользоваться функцией NOW() или CURRENT-TIMESTAMP() вместо CURRENT-DATE(). Разница в том, что последние учитывают еще и текущее время, а не только дату...
Собственно, если Вы хотите то поведение, которое описано в ответе от Мордехай Гутерман, то мой код Вам не поможет... по той простой причине, что в таком случае, на мой взгляд, необходимо добавлять в таблицу еще одно поле, значение которого будет показывать, была ли новость уже отображена и сколько времени....

Answer (score 0):

А если в течение одного дня добавится в базу сразу 5 новостей? То каждая будет держаться по 2 дня, таким образом, последняя появится только тогда, когда устареет на 10 дней... 
Вы именно этого хотите?

Если нет, то стоит подумать, чтобы показывать сразу несколько новостей, которые пришли за последние 2 дня... И запрос простой будет...

**Добавлено.**

Средствами mysql можно решить все, но только не нужно стараться сделать все одним запросом.  Очевидно, что результат - выводить или нет каждую новость - зависит от обработки всех предыдущих новостей... Запрос будет сложным и неэффективным, лучше решить задачу по другому... Как Вы и пишете: при добавлении новой записи подстраивать дату (или добавить специальное поле)

То есть получаете:

```
select max(date) as date from news
```

и пишем в базу `полученная дата < current_date() ? current_date()+2 : полученная дата +2`.

Comment: > Вы именно этого хотите? Да, именно этого. @gote, спасибо, пока нет возможности попробывать, позже отпишу :)

Answer (score 0):

А я даты в БД храню как INT и удобно работать. Запросы типа

```sql
SELECT bla-bla FROM bla 
WHERE `date`<=".$date-(2*24*60*60)." 
ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 1
```